# Magento links are populating by it self

Tags: php, html, magento, hyperlink

I am using magento for one of my projects and I put this code as a footer

```
<div class="left">

<a href="../australia/index.php/p">P</a> | <a href="../australia/index.php/w">W</a> 

</div>
```

What it does in safari and chrome I get link www.something.com/australia/index.php/p/australia/australia/australia/australia/australia/australia/australia/australia/australia/australia/australia/australia

I dont knwo why it works in firefox

Comment: What you want to do exactly.Are you trying to point static page or you want to redirect this url to some external website?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `../australia` with `/australia`.  If it has to go back one folder then use the relative path from root, like `/mysubfolder/australia/`.

Comment: Tha was first thing that I tried but I got problems that magento gives on homepage automaticly www.something.com/english/index.php because Iam using more language versions of website.